# Restrict access to xmlrpc.php in Pyrocms

Tags: apache, codeigniter, pyrocms

I recently noted a huge amount of traffic hitting to the xmlrpc.php

I blocked the IP address which is a temparary solution. How I block access to xmlrpc.php file in Pyrocms.

Answer (score 0):

You might try chmod'ing it to your PHP user only.